# Query interface in python COM server

Tags: python, xslt, com, win32com, pythoncom

I am currently starting with win32com package. I have XSL file where I am using COM object programmed in Python:

```
<xsl:value-of select="plugin:GetTest(.)"/>
```

XSL transformation is done using MSXML2 XSL processor and python COM object is injected using *addObject* method.
Implementation of the *GetTest* method is as follows:

```
    def GetTest(self, obj):
        IID_IXMLDOMNode = IID("{2933BF80-7B36-11d2-B20E-00C04F983E60}")
        try:
            node = win32com.client.Dispatch(obj, None, IID_IXMLDOMNode)
            #node = obj.QueryInterface(IID_IXMLDOMNode)
            return node.get_text()
        except Exception as e:
            return format_exc()
```

The *obj* argument has type *PyIDispatch*. In order to work with my IXMLDOMNode node interface I have to obtain it somehow, right? However, the uncommented approach fails with

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.get_text
```

And the commented approach fails with

```
obj.QueryInterface(IID_IXMLDOMNode)<\u000d>pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported'
```

Can anybody has suggestion what am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never used MSXML with Python so I can't assess the Python part of the code but as far as I remember from JScript or VBScript when you use e.g. `foo:method(.)` on the XSLT side you don't pass a single node to the method but rather a selection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759171(v=vs.85).aspx so you might want to try whether your Python code can be adapted to cast to a selection and not a node.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, the _obj_ is DOM selection

Answer (score 0):

I had two mistakes in the code, firstly, the *obj* is not selected node but DOM selection (thanks Martin Honnen), secondly, IXMLDOMNode hasn't _get_text_ method

```
def GetTest(self, obj):
    try:
        selector = win32com.client.Dispatch(obj, None, IID_IXMLDOMSelection)

        out = []

        for node in selector:
            out.append(node.nodeName)

        return ", ".join(out)
    except Exception as e:
        return format_exc()
```